# Quartz only the first job in a row is executed

Tags: quartz-scheduler

We have implemented recurring tasks using Quartz scheduler in our app. The user may schedule a recurring task starting at any time, even starting in the past. So for example, I can schedule a task to run monthly, starting on the 1st July, even though today is 17th July.

I would expect Quartz to run the first job immediately if it is in the past, and any subsequent jobs I throw at it. However, today I encountered a case when the task didn't get triggered instantly. The task was scheduled for 15th July, today is 17th July. Nothing happened. After I restarted the server and the code to schedule all the tasks in the DB ran, it **did** get triggered. Why would that happen ?

Code for scheduling the task below. Note that to make it recurring, we just reschedule it with the same code for another date we calculate (but that part of the code doesn't matter for the issue at hand).

**Edit**: Only the first job gets triggered, any subsequent jobs are not. If I try to use startNow() instead of startAt(Date), it still doesn't work, makes no difference.

```
    JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(ScheduledAppJob.class)
                              .withIdentity(stringId)
                              .build();

    Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                                    .withIdentity(stringId)
                                    .startAt(date)
                                    .build();

    try
    {
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm:ss");
        String recurringTime = dateFormat.format(date);
        logger.info("Scheduling recurring job for " + recurringTime);
    }
    catch (SchedulerException se)
    {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**quartz.properties** file, located under src/main (tried even in WEB-INF and WEB-INF/classes like suggested in the tutorial, but made no difference); even tried with 20 threadCount, still no difference:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = AppScheduler
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 3
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be working now. Haven't ran into any more problems. Could've been a config issue, as I have moved the config file in `/src/main/resources`.
Also try turning logging on in order to help with the debug:

```
log4j.logger.com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit=DEBUG
```

We also added a JobTriggerListener to help with the logs:

```
private static class JobTriggerListener implements TriggerListener
    {
        private String name;

        public JobTriggerListener(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }

        public void triggerComplete(Trigger trigger, JobExecutionContext context,
                                    Trigger.CompletedExecutionInstruction triggerInstructionCode)
        {

        }

        public void triggerFired(Trigger trigger, JobExecutionContext context)
        {

        }

        public void triggerMisfired(Trigger trigger)
        {
            logger.warn("Trigger misfired for trigger: " + trigger.getKey());
            try
            {
                logger.info("Available threads: " + scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs());
            }
            catch (SchedulerException ex)
            {
                logger.error("Could not get currently executing jobs.", ex);
            }
        }

        public boolean vetoJobExecution(Trigger trigger, JobExecutionContext context)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Check the **updated config file**:

```
#============================================================================
# Configure Main Scheduler Properties
#============================================================================

org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck = true
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyAppScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO

#============================================================================
# Configure ThreadPool
#============================================================================

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 25
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 9

#============================================================================
# Configure JobStore
#============================================================================

org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
```